# Version Code Reverts After Extracting

Tags: android, eclipse, version

I have run a new version of an Android app in Eclipse with a new version code in the manifest. However, when I extract the signed version of the app the version code reverts back to 1 in the manifest. How do I get a signed app with a new version code?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the projects before exporting